# Clojure - HTML Decoder

Tags: clojure

Are there any good HTML decoders in clojure?

I have tried a few out such as the ones from `clojure.tools.html-utils` and `codec` from `ring` but they don't decode the html fully, ie there are still some encoded symbols.

If I put my code to be decoded in a website such as https://opinionatedgeek.com/Codecs/HtmlDecoder , for example, the HTML decodes properly into text.

The type of text I am getting is  `Broad Institute of MIT and Harvard - Cambridge&#x2F;Boston, MA - ONSITE<p>Do you want to help cure cancer? Do you care about the mission behind your software engineering?<p>We are a motivated team of software engineers building scalable tools to analyze massive amounts of genomic data using cloud compute software to process 24TB of biological data daily... and that&#x27;s just the beginning! We are co-developing products to advance science with the biggest partners in the industry -- working directly with and alongside their engineers.<p>We are seeking strong software engineers to join our team. We have a flat organizational structure with self-directed, agile teams.<p>We use Scala, Spark, Akka, React &amp; Clojurescript. Experience in the tech stack or sciences not req&#x27;d.<p>Here is some recent information on our mission: <a href="http:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.wbur.org&#x2F;commonhealth&#x2F;2016&#x2F;07&#x2F;07&#x2F;precision-medicine-broad" rel="nofollow">http:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.wbur.org&#x2F;commonhealth&#x2F;2016&#x2F;07&#x2F;07&#x2F;precision-medici...</a><p>Interested? Please email Amy Massey - massey@broadinstitute.org/n/n/nID is https://news.ycombinator.com/item?`

When you put this through the website I linked above you get `Broad Institute of MIT and Harvard - Cambridge/Boston, MA - ONSITEDo you want to help cure cancer? Do you care about the mission behind your software engineering?We are a motivated team of software engineers building scalable tools to analyze massive amounts of genomic data using cloud compute software to process 24TB of biological data daily... and that's just the beginning! We are co-developing products to advance science with the biggest partners in the industry -- working directly with and alongside their engineers.We are seeking strong software engineers to join our team. We have a flat organizational structure with self-directed, agile teams.We use Scala, Spark, Akka, React & Clojurescript. Experience in the tech stack or sciences not req'd.Here is some recent information on our mission: http://www.wbur.org/commonhealth/2016/07/07/precision-medici...Interested? Please email Amy Massey - massey@broadinstitute.org/n/n/nID is https://news.ycombinator.com/item?`

This is how I want it to look

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/nathell/clj-tagsoup or https://github.com/weavejester/crouton?

Comment: Another is [Hickory](https://github.com/davidsantiago/hickory), which can be used from both Clojure and ClojureScript.

Answer (score 1):

```clj
(import '[org.jsoup Jsoup])
(.text (Jsoup/parse s))
```

Taken from [crouton](https://github.com/weavejester/crouton/blob/master/src/crouton/html.clj#L65)